# Complicated Woocommerce shipping Rules issue

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I am trying to apply complicated shipping rules in Woocommerce.

I have basic products which is:

| Spend | Shipping cost |
| --- | --- |
| less than 300 | 30$ |
| 300 or more | Free |

But I also have some large products and products with special delivery requirements

| product | Shipping Class | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| large box | Truck with crane | 1000$ |
| large Box | Truck only | 200$ |
| Gazebo (Choice1: Delivery Only) | Delivery & Assebly | 200$ |
| Gazebo (Choice2: Delivery & Assembly) | Delivery & Assebly | 350$ |

Below is my shipping methods

[Shipping Methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuCs5.png)

[Standerd rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7HiO.png)

[Shipping With Assembly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMEQi.png)

For basic products everything is working well,

Also for large boxes its well as it shows in Standard shipping.

But when I add the (shipping with assembly) shipping method it still appear as choice even if no product with this class is in the cart.

I just need it to appear only when gazebo is in the cart

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_when_class_is_in_cart', 100, 2 );
```

function hide_shipping_when_class_is_in_cart( $rates, $package ) {

```
$free_shipping_method = 'free_shipping:13';
$shipping_classes = array('truck-crane','large-furniture','furniture-assembly');
$class_exists = false;
$cart_classes = array();
$shipping_methods = $shipping_zone->get_shipping_methods();

foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item )
        $cart_item_class = $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class();
    if( in_array($cart_item_class ,  $shipping_classes ) ) {//Check if any shipping class exist
        array_push($cart_classes,$cart_item_class); //push cart classes to array
        $class_exists = true;
        //break; 
    }


foreach($shipping_methods as $method){
    $method_classes = $method->get_shipping_classes();

  //Here i want to unset shipping methods which has no avaiable class in cart items

}

if( $class_exists )
    unset( $rates[$free_shipping_method] );

return $rates;
```

}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding the service like 'assembly' as a choice that comes with the product

my code below

```
/**
 ** Display Fields
 */
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_shipping', 'woocommerce_product_custom_product_service');
function woocommerce_product_custom_product_service()
{
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field"><span class="wrap">';
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_custom_product_service_label',
            'placeholder' => 'Service Label',
            'label' => __('Custom Service', 'woocommerce'),

        )
    );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_custom_product_service_fees',
            'placeholder' => 'Service Fees',
            'type' => 'number',
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                'step' => 'any',
                'min' => '0'
            )
        )
    );
echo '</span></div>';
}

/**
 ** Save Fields
 */ 
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_product_service_save');

function woocommerce_product_custom_product_service_save($post_id)
{
    $woocommerce_custom_product_service_label = $_POST['_custom_product_service_label'];
    $woocommerce_custom_product_service_fees = $_POST['_custom_product_service_fees'];

    if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_product_service_label) && !empty($woocommerce_custom_product_service_fees)){
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_service_label', esc_attr($woocommerce_custom_product_service_label));
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_service_fees', esc_attr($woocommerce_custom_product_service_fees));
    }elseif(empty($woocommerce_custom_product_service_label) && empty($woocommerce_custom_product_service_fees)){
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_service_label', '');
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_service_fees', '');
        }
}





/**
 ** Product page form
 */ 
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','add_custom_product_service_to_single_product', 2 );
function add_custom_product_service_to_single_product(){
    global $product;

    if( !$product->get_meta( '_custom_product_service_label' ) && !$product->get_meta( '_custom_product_service_fees' )) return;

    add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_custom_product_service_option', 30 );
}

function add_custom_product_service_option(){
    global $product;

    $active_price = (float) $product->get_price();
    $service_label =  $product->get_meta( '_custom_product_service_label' );
    $service_price = (float) $product->get_meta( '_custom_product_service_fees' );
    $service_price_html   = strip_tags( wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array('price' => $service_price ) ) ) );
    $active_price_html   = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product ) );
    $disp_price_sum_html = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array('price' => $active_price + $service_price ) ) );

    echo '<div class="hidden-field">
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="service_option_field" data-priority="">
    <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><label class="checkbox"> ' .$service_label.' '.__("Service:", "Woocommerce") .
    ' <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox " name="service_option" id="service_option" value="1"> +' . $service_price_html .
    '</label></span></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="service_price" value="' . $service_price . '">
    <input type="hidden" name="active_price" value="' . $active_price . '"></div>';

    // Jquery: Update displayed price
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        var cb = 'input[name="service_option"]'
            pp = 'p.price';
        // On change / select a variation
        $('form.cart').on( 'change', cb, function(){
            if( $(cb).prop('checked') === true )
                $(pp).html('<?php echo $disp_price_sum_html.__("(Assembly Included)", "Woocommerce"); ?>');
            else
                $(pp).html('<?php echo $active_price_html; ?>');
        })
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}

/**
 ** Add to Cart
 */ 
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_product_service_data', 10, 3);
function add_custom_product_service_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    if (isset($_POST['service_option']) && !empty($_POST['service_option'])) {
        $cart_item_data['new_price'] = (float) ($_POST['active_price'] + $_POST['service_price']);
        $cart_item_data['service_price'] = (float) $_POST['service_price'];
        $cart_item_data['active_price'] = (float) $_POST['active_price'];

       foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item){
            if(($product_id == $cart_item['product_id']) && !empty($cart_item['service_price'])){
             $unique_key = $cart_item['unique_key'];
            break;
            }
       }
   
        if(!empty($unique_key)){
            $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = $unique_key;
        }else{
            $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5(microtime().rand());
        }

    return $cart_item_data;
}}


/**
 ** Set the new calculated cart item price
 */  
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_product_service_custom_price', 20, 1);

function add_custom_product_service_custom_price($cart) {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        if (isset($cart_item['new_price']))
            $cart_item['data']->set_price((float) $cart_item['new_price']);
    }
}


/**
 ** Display in Cart
 */ 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_product_service_item_data', 10, 2);

function display_custom_product_service_item_data($cart_item_data, $cart_item) {
        $_product = new WC_Product( $cart_item['product_id'] );
        $service_label = $_product->get_meta( '_custom_product_service_label' );
    if (isset($cart_item['service_price'])) {
        //$service_label = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], '_custom_product_service_label' );
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => $service_label .__(" Service Fees", "woocommerce"),
            'value' => strip_tags( '+ ' . wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $cart_item['data'], array('price' => $cart_item['service_price'] ) ) ) )
        );
    }elseif(!empty($service_label)){
             $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => $service_label .__(" Service Not Included", "woocommerce"),
           'value' => strip_tags( '+ ' . wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $cart_item['data'], array('price' => $cart_item['service_price'] ) ) ) )
        );
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}
```